# Repeated Error in SQL Server 2017 Error Log (Error: 15404, error-code 0x5)

Tags: sql-server-2017, scom, system-center

I'm relatively new to SQLServer2017 Developer and System Center Operations Manager however I was asked to set up a SCOM test environment for our network. However, I keep receiving this error about one of my SCOM service accounts. I have already looked at some fixes and applied them however after refreshing the log the same error message still keeps appearing.

```
    2020-02-13 14:03:09.05 spid47s     An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15404, State: 19. Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'OMDASTest', error code 0x5.
```